# insert author name in table of content

Tags: lyx

I am using latex editor **LyX**. I write a book with many authors. I want to list each author name in each chapter in table of content.

How can I list author name in table of content?

Comment: Where exactly do you want this author name to appear? In a separate line above the chapter? If so, you can use the `\addtocontents{toc}{Author name}` command before the chapter. In Lyx you can use the insert-tex-code-button to insert this command directly. You have to compile twice to see the effect, but I think lyx does this anyway

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `\addtocontents{type}{text}` command. "Type" is the name of the contents file generated by latex. For the tableof contents this is `toc`, for the list of figures `lof` and the list of tables `lot`.

```
\addtocontents{toc}{Author 1}
\chapter{Blubb}
```

Should add the name of the author before the chapter in the table of contents. You need to compile twice to see changes in the TOC.

In Lyx you have to add the command with the tex-button. Put the courser before the chapter, press the tex-button and a red box will appear. In that box enter the above command.

Comment: However, it will probably not give quite nice output. On the other hand, without having a MWE (which is difficult from LyX), not much more can be done...

Comment: @tohecz exactly :)